# Time zone getting changed after using endOf('quarter') on moment js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm using the followiing approach to get the end of a quarter:

```js
function convertToMomentDates(dates) {
  return dates.map((date) => moment(date).tz("Europe/Rome"));
}

function getEndOfQuarter(dates) {
    const lastDate = dates.pop();
  if (!lastDate || !lastDate.isValid()) return null;
    console.log(lastDate.endOf("quarter").format());
    return lastDate.endOf("quarter").format();
}

const dates = [
  "2018-10-01T01:00:00+01:00",
  "2019-01-01T01:00:00+01:00",
];

const endOfQuarterResult = getEndOfQuarter(convertToMomentDates(dates));

console.log(
  endOfQuarterResult ===
    "2019-03-31T23:59:59+01:00"
);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = endOfQuarterResult;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I mean I'm using all my dates with +1:00 offset and it gets changed to +2:00 after the endOf function, what would be the correct implementation in order to not change the offset...

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have some date, and that is getting converted to +2:00 timezone. But isn't that happening `convertToMomentDates` in this function?  If you don't want the timezone to change, you can remove the ".tz" function .

Comment: @iatsi when applying the tz on convertToMomentDates function, it keeps the +1:00... The offset change only occurs after the endOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this case the expected result is ok due accoridng Italy/Rome timezone at the end of march, in this case the end of the last quarter it the offset changes to +2. more infor could be seen on this url: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/italy/rome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).